# What programming language links does TDengine support?

Tags: database

I would like to know which programming languages are supported by TDengine

such as C, C++, Java, PHP, Python, and Go?

I am engaged in the development of Industrial internet of things. I have several old systems that I used to have, and I want to access TDengine

Answer (score 1):

*Note that this isn't an area where I have expertise.  I was just looking for potentially AI-generated answers and came across this question.*

According to [the TDEngine documentation](https://docs.tdengine.com/intro/#:%7E:text=Provides%20connectors%20for%20C%2FC%2B%2B%2C%20Java%2C%20Python%2C,Go%2C%20Rust%2C%20Node.js%20and%20other%20programming%20languages.), it:

> Provides connectors for C/C++, [Java](https://github.com/taosdata/taos-connector-jdbc), [Python](https://github.com/taosdata/taos-connector-python), [Go](https://github.com/taosdata/driver-go), [Rust](https://github.com/taosdata/taos-connector-rust), [Node.js](https://github.com/taosdata/taos-connector-node) and other programming languages.

*(links added)*

In the "other" category, I also see [.NET](https://github.com/taosdata/taos-connector-dotnet) in their [repo list](https://github.com/orgs/taosdata/repositories?type=all).